# Upgrading to Spring 3.0.3.RELEASE - Where can I find a history of the jars?

Tags: spring

I'm trying to upgrade an application that's using Spring 2.5.6 to the latest (3.0.3.RELEASE) version and I'm using the Spring repository to find the latest versions of the jars I need:
http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/library/versiondetail?name=org.springframework.spring&version=3.0.3.RELEASE

I'm at version 2.0.8 for spring-mock.  I've found documentation that says spring-mock moved into spring-test with 2.5.x but according to the repository spring-test doesn't exist anymore in 3.0.3.RELEASE.  I'm also having trouble tracking down what has happened to spring-tx and spring-webmvc-struts since 2.5.6.

Do any of you know what's happened to these jars (i.e. moved, deprecated) and where I can find documentation?

Comment: why don't you just look inside the Spring 3 JAR files?

Answer (score 3):

I have all the jars you mention jars currently in a project. I just used Maven, the simplest way to get the jars you are looking for:

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```